# Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 16 and 32 (The offending index is 0)

Tags: python

I'm getting following error :

> Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 16 and 32 (The offending index is 0)

in following code:

```
x1=self.avg_pool(l1)
print('x1:', x1.shape)
x2=self.avg_pool(l2)
print('x2:', x2.shape)
x3=self.avg_pool(l3)
print('x3:', x3.shape)
x4=self.avg_pool(l4)
print('x4:', x4.shape) 
x = self.aspp(x)
print('x:', x.shape)
x=torch.cat((x4,x3,x2,x1,x),dim=1)
cout1=x
```

I'm getting shapes of x1,x2,x3,x4,x as

```
x1: torch.Size([5, 256, 32, 32])
x2: torch.Size([5, 512, 32, 32])
x3: torch.Size([5, 1024, 32, 32])
x4: torch.Size([5, 2048, 32, 32])
x: torch.Size([5, 256, 16, 16])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating on `dim=1`, well that means you need to join the tensors one after the othe ralong `dim=1`. The value that you get after concatenation along `dim=1` is `value=256+512+1024+2048+256`, provided shapes of the tensors match in other dimensions too. The size of `tensor x` should be `x=(5,256,32,32)`.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs (values of l1, l2, l3, l4) are not provided, so I just guessed it and tried to mimic your code. Below snippet works fine.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Pyramid_Pooling(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, levels, inChans, outChans):

        super(Pyramid_Pooling, self).__init__()
        self.inChans = inChans
        self.outChans = outChans
        assert len(levels) == 4

        self.pool_4 = nn.AvgPool2d((levels[3], levels[3]))
        self.pool_3 = nn.AvgPool2d((levels[2], levels[2]))
        self.pool_2 = nn.AvgPool2d((levels[1], levels[1]))
        self.pool_1 = nn.AvgPool2d((levels[0], levels[0]))
        
        # lower the number of channels to desired size
        self.bottleneck_pyramid = nn.Conv2d(
            self.inChans, self.outChans, kernel_size=1
        )

    def forward(self, en1, en2, en3, en4):
        pooled_out_1 = self.pool_1(en1)
        print(pooled_out_1.shape)
        pooled_out_2 = self.pool_2(en2)
        print(pooled_out_2.shape)
        pooled_out_3 = self.pool_3(en3)
        print(pooled_out_3.shape)
        pooled_out_4 = self.pool_4(en4)
        print(pooled_out_4.shape)
        
        cat = torch.cat((pooled_out_1, pooled_out_2, pooled_out_3, pooled_out_4), 1)
        out = self.bottleneck_pyramid(cat)
        
        return out
```

I tried to guess your inputs and issue might be somehwere in input dimensions. You want to output 32 x 32 then input should be like below. Also added a 1x1 conv to lower the channels to desired output.

```
x_train_0 = torch.randn((3, 256, 32, 32), device = torch.device('cuda'))
x_train_1 = torch.randn((3, 512, 64, 64), device = torch.device('cuda'))
x_train_2 = torch.randn((3, 1024, 128, 128), device = torch.device('cuda'))
x_train_3 = torch.randn((3, 2048, 256, 256), device = torch.device('cuda'))

inChans = x_train_0.shape[1] + x_train_1.shape[1] + x_train_2.shape[1] + x_train_3.shape[1]
outChans = 512

# kernel_size = [1,2,4,8]
pyramid_pooling = Pyramid_Pooling([1, 2, 4, 8], inChans, outChans)
pyramid_pooling.to(torch.device('cuda'))
out = pyramid_pooling(x_train_0, x_train_1, x_train_2, x_train_3)
print(f"Output shape: {out.shape}")
```

Output will look like this:

```
torch.Size([3, 256, 32, 32])
torch.Size([3, 512, 32, 32])
torch.Size([3, 1024, 32, 32])
torch.Size([3, 2048, 32, 32])
Output shape: torch.Size([3, 512, 32, 32])
```